# Problem with referencing CSS and JavaScript files relatively

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have an IIS web site. This web site contains other web sites so the structure is like this.

```
\ 
MainWebSite\
        Scripts\
        CSS\
        App1\
           Scripts\
           CSS\
        App2\
           Scripts\
           CSS\
```

All sites are ASP.NET MVC web applications.

In the `MasterPage` of App1, I reference the script files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js">
</script>
```

The problem is that it now tries to find the file at http:\server\MainWebSite\Scripts....

How can I work around that? Should I put all my scripts and CSS files into the root directory, is that a preferred solution?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly is the problem with this? Are there pages in different directories so the relative link breaks?

Comment: Are your script and css files located in MainWebSite\Scripts?

Comment: no but u couldnt know that sry, they are like i added now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET there is a great function that is part of the Page Object:

```
ResolveUrl(String)
```

This is used by passing in a relative string, but the best part is you can use the ~ to symbolize the root of your website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveURL("~/PATH_FROM_ROOT/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js")%>'></script>
```

[Note the single quotes.]

Comment: I know this is insignificant comment as any developer will know and Markus understood himself. Still wanna say you have not closed parenthesis and render block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" runat="server"></script>
```

In the above markup, I'm assuming that your script files are in MainWebSite\Scripts\

"~" brings your reletive reference from your application root directory. The benefit is that if you shift your master page file from `MainWebSite\App1\` to `MainWebSite\App1\MasterPages\` you will not have to change all the relatively referenced urls in your master page.

Comment: ~ does not work unless you are on a server control or if you use the ResolveURL function. And in ASP.NET you cannot make a script tag runat="server" for JS

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use absolute URLs for CSS and JavaScript. Using an appending global variable you can also use it on your development system, too.